# ASP.NET Post request called on page load with Webclient not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http-post, webclient

I'm integrating OAuth into a ASP.NET Webforms application, and I'm trying to make a post request using WebClient synchronously to get an access_token. It doesn't give an errors, but the Response.Redirect at the bottom isn't firing, and there doesn't seem to be any record of the post request or response. I'm calling the method in page load as the Authorisation Code is returned to to this page as query string. Am I doing something silly? Any help would be appreciated!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                String authorisationcode = Request.QueryString["code"];
                if (authorisationcode != null)
                {
                    MicrosoftAuthorisation(authorisationcode);
                }
        }

protected void MicrosoftAuthorisation(String AuthCode)
        {
                String MicrosoftClientId = HttpContext.Current.Application["MicrosoftClientId"].ToString();
                String MicrosoftRedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Application["MicrosoftRedirectUri"].ToString();

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var values = new NameValueCollection();
                    values["client_id"] = MicrosoftClientId;
                    values["scope"] = "openid";
                    values["code"] = AuthCode;
                    values["redirect_uri"] = MicrosoftRedirectUri;
                    values["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";

                    var response = client.UploadValues("https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token", values);

                    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
                    Response.Redirect("loginauthorisation.aspx");
                }
        }
```

Comment: Are you following an example of how to do this, or are you just using the documentation?

Comment: Hi Neil, I'm, following this. At the point where I'm trying to retrieve an Access_token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: My guess is you have an exception inside `client.UploadValues`.  Put a try catch around the function and see if you get one.  Are you sure `UploadValues` is the correct function, and not `UploadString` or `UploadData` ?

Comment: Thanks Neil, try and catch show that it is throwing an exception and is being caught. I've tried also with uploadstring and a string of parameters. Without the try and catch shouldn't I be able to see the attempted post request in Chrome inspect element - network tab?

Comment: I'm expecting JSON to be returned, and having used apirequest.IO, i'm getting bad request response due to the code expiring (timestamp is an hour earlier than it should be). In this case I still get a JSON response (albeit an error). In my application I'm not receiving any response, should I get one if the request is bad?

Comment: You won't see anything in Chrome, because it's not Chrome making the request, it's the server (C# code, nothing to do with the browser).